# ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend When running jar file using flink

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have downloaded Apache Flink on Microsoft Windows and ran the `start-local.sh`. It worked and I can successfully access the web interface by navigating to `http://localhost:8081/`.

But when i try to run the first example using `./bin/flink run ./examples/batch/WordCount.jar`,
I keep getting the following error. I tried different versions of Flink, all yielding the same error.
[image: error message]

Comment: The Flink community only supports the two most recent minor releases, which are 1.16 and 1.15. The docs for version 1.1 are here -- https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.1/  -- but I don't see anything in them specially about running Flink on windows. Can you try a more recent version of Flink?